# Sample code for finding location using IP address in java?

Tags: java, location, ip

I am looking for the sample code to get Exact Location of IP.
I did goggling but haven't find any Sample code.
Thank You..

Comment: let me test. nullPainter

Comment: Note that the free versions of the MaxMind databases are updated less regularly than the commercial versions. Also note that the notion of 'exact location' is relative when it comes to IP and may be based on the city where your ISP is based, depending on the size of your country, ISP etc.

Comment: check the ip2asn2cc library: https://github.com/AxLabs/ip2asn2cc

Answer (score 3):

I've used the MaxMind GeoIP Lite database to good success before. Both [city and country databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite) and [APIs](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable) are available.

An example of usage is:

```
File dbfile = new File("db/GeoLiteCity.dat");
LookupService lookupService = new LookupService(dbfile, LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);

Location location = lookupService.getLocation(ipAddress);

// Populate region. Note that regionName is a MaxMind class, not an instance variable
if (location != null) {
    location.region = regionName.regionNameByCode(location.countryCode, location.region);
}
```

Comment: try this code in here  http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/

Comment: Did this answer ever solve your problems, @KhAn SaAb? If so, it'd be great if it coudl be marked as accepted.