# How do I check where "unknown sessions" comes from in my Tomcat server?

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

There are lots of sessions like this in my `Apache Tomcat/7.0.47` server:
[image]

By "lots" I mean, for example:
 - 16 Active sessions total
 - 6 Unknown sessions

In this server, there is a web application. (JSF 2.2.3, PrimeFaces 4, Jersey 1.18 Rest Service)

Is there a way I can trace these sessions? Or some leaks I can check in my project?

Comment: What are unknown sessions?

Comment: Do you have any ViewScoped or SessionScoped pages that do not require the user to login before accessing them? JSF will have to start a throwaway HttpSession in order to store the bean state.

Comment: @Stefan, I had to put a name to the sessions I don't know where they came from, since English isn't my first language, unknown sessions seemed appropriate.

Comment: @AliCheaito the page's bean are RequestScoped before the user logs in.

Comment: Ok, you mean the geo location/locale? See here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185703/sample-code-for-finding-location-using-ip-address-in-java

Comment: @Stefan, no, I mean how are they created and stays active on the session list. Is there a way to find out what/who created it?