# Using Environment variables in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables

I am using sprint boot. I want to check what is current location where that spring boot application is running. I figured out making use of environment variable on spring but no idea on how to get the location.

The environment variable should send the location of current application running as it could be deployed in various locations ex:  U.S/India.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion solution will be in 2 steps:

**Step 1 : Get the public IP of the machine where code is being executed.**

```
URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(whatismyip.openStream()));
String ip = in.readLine(); // Public IP of machine
```

**Step 2 : Get the location by that IP address**

For that you can use **MaxMind GeoIP Lite database** as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16185735/4762502) in another answer or [article](https://mkyong.com/java/java-find-location-using-ip-address/).